# Stars rendering on Rails 3 app

Tags: image, view, ruby-on-rails-3.2, src

I have a Rails 3 app where users can add a rating to a review which is an integer between 1 and 5.
Following Ryan Bates railscast, I want to display that rating using a star system, and I thus added these methods to my ApplicationController:

```
def render_stars(rating)
  content_tag :div, star_images(rating), :class => 'stars'
end

def star_images(rating)
  (0...5).map do |position|
    star_image(((rating-position)*2).round)
  end.join
end

def star_image(value)
  image_tag "/images/star-#{star_type(value)}.png", :size => '15x15'
end

def star_type(value)
  if value <= 0
    'off'
  elsif value == 1
    'half'
  else
    'on'
  end
end
```

In my reviews#index view, when I add the line:

```
<%= render_stars(review.rating) %>
```

The methods work fine but instead of getting the images of the stars in my view, I get instead the html:

```
<img alt="Star-on" height="15" src="/images/star-on.png" width="15" /><img alt="Star-on" height="15" src="/images/star-on.png" width="15" /><img alt="Star-on" height="15" src="/images/star-on.png" width="15" /><img alt="Star-on" height="15" src="/images/star-on.png" width="15" /><img alt="Star-off" height="15" src="/images/star-off.png" width="15" />
```

Any idea why it's not showing the images and I get theses lines instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `html_safe` like this:

```
star_images(rating).html_safe
```